# How to run android emulator on amazon ec2?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-studio, amazon-ec2

Well, I already go through several blogs to run an android emulator on amazon ec2, but none of them works, and they are generally 3 to 5 years old.

Would like to know, do we have any alternative, way, crack in 2021 to run android studio & emulator on Amazon EC2 instance(Ubuntu or Windows Server) without using any third party like Bluestacks, and for free?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

1. use regular ec2 instance like this example -  [Android-Emulator-on-AWS-EC2](https://gist.github.com/atyachin/cf1690085173e1fabc07b9acc7af3de6)
   I tried it and it works well, but you don't have any fun way to get
   the emulator with GUI and you can work only with ADB.
2. Use bare metal instances like c5.metal (The cost is $4 per hour) this is a good guide on how to do it.[Deploying Android Emulators on AWS EC2](https://medium.com/heuristics/deploying-android-emulators-on-aws-ec2-1-3-arm-architecture-and-genymotion-solutions-for-a-2ef3238542d5)  in this link he explains the difference between the instances.

Answer (score 1):

Genymotion can be run in AWS and is available through AWS Marketplace or through EC2 AMIs. You can interact with the device through a web based interface. It's not free, but you pay per used time (on top of any EC2 charges).
https://docs.genymotion.com/paas/02_Getting_Started/021_AWS/